# What effect on internet crime did the more recent developments in encryption have?

Tags: encryption, crime

I'm doing a presentation on the effect of encryption on internet enabled/based crime, what would people say is the largest development in encryption of say the last 5-10 years what and what kind of enabling effect did it have?

Comment: This question is basically opinion-based, but I like it. 16-20 years ago, Few people really knew how to hide their activities online. Today, with the invention of many different privacy enhancement programs, including proper encryption, it's much harder to find out what people are doing online. Note that I said, "much harder." It's not impossible. These days, criminals use TOR heavily, but not all criminals use TOR. And not all TOR users are criminals. If you ask me, this is also too broad to answer... good question, though.

Comment: People also do far, far more online now than 16-20 years ago and the encryption is a double edged sword as it undoubtedly prevents a tremendous amount of internet crime concurrent to "allowing" it.

Answer (score 1):

Largest development in cryptography (at least breaking it) would be specialized hardware, there are countless examples of hardware specifically designed to test hashes at a speed that is unattainable with general-use hardware including variations [designed to calculate bcrypt hashes](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/woot14/woot14-malvoni.pdf), which ironically was created to beat specialized hardware in the first place.

Specialized hardware is the reason that we cannot rely on password hashing techniques that don't require a significant work factor to calculate using as many resources as possible in a way that doesn't promote parallelism.  The newest up and coming password hashing technique is [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), which heavily uses RAM and many randomly placed accesses to large arrays of random information which is by far the toughest resource to run in parallel.

As hardware becomes faster still and the cost of hardware becoming less of a barrier with the advent of renting specialized hardware for a cheap fee, I suspect that the future of password hashing will only become more dependent on counteracting the specialized resources of adversaries while still providing an hashing technique that doesn't put a toll on general-use server hardware.

Comment: Side note note: I am completely blown away by the article linked in the first paragraph. This is amazing.

Comment: @MarkBuffalo I'll be honest, I gulped when I first saw the article myself.

Comment: And not to mention, those with lots of money should be able to make a much larger, scalable version of it. I've actually updated my BBC password post with a link to this article.